# How to define a method (of my own class) that must be invoked

Tags: java

I'm writing a class to manage files locking named *FileLocker*.
Its buildier method locks a file (which directory is received as a method's parameter) thanks to *java.nio.channels.FileLock*.The *FileLocker* class also contains a release() method that release the FileLock created in its buildier method. The problem is that the release() method *have to* be called, otherwise the file's lock will never be released and other processes won't be allowed to use this file (during the current JVM). **So my question is:** Does exist a way to indicate that release() method have to be called in all codes that use a *FileLocker* object, so that during those codes compilations an error is thrown if release() method isn't used? (Here I post *FileLocker* class code, just to show how it works):

```
package essentialServer_Service;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.channels.FileLock;
import java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException;
import essentialServer_Exception.EssentialServerException;

public class FileLocker implements ServerConfiguration{

String fileDirectory;
int filelockingAttempts;
int maxFilelockingAttempts;
FileChannel fileChannel;
RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile;
FileLock lock;
file f;

public FileLocker (String fileDirectory) throws EssentialServerException {

    this.fileDirectory = fileDirectory;
    filelockingAttempts = 0;
    maxFilelockingAttempts = maxDatabaseFilesLockingAttempts();
    f = new file(fileDirectory);
    f.make(); // To open a channel for a specific file, this file must exist
              // Note that the file.make() method throws an EssentialServerException if it seems to be impossible to create the file
    fileChannel = null;
    randomAccessFile = null;
    try{
        randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(f, "rw");
        fileChannel = randomAccessFile.getChannel();
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        throw new EssentialServerException(4);
    }
    lock = null;
    while (true) {
        try{
            lock = fileChannel.tryLock();
        }catch (OverlappingFileLockException e){
            filelockingAttempts++;
            if (filelockingAttempts > maxFilelockingAttempts && maxFilelockingAttempts > -1){
                try{
                    fileChannel.close();
                    randomAccessFile.close();
                }catch (IOException ee){
                    throw new EssentialServerException(7);
                }
                throw new EssentialServerException(5);
            }
        }catch (IOException e) {
            filelockingAttempts++;
            if (filelockingAttempts > maxFilelockingAttempts && maxFilelockingAttempts > -1){
                try{
                    fileChannel.close();
                    randomAccessFile.close();
                }catch (IOException ee){
                    throw new EssentialServerException(8);
                }
                throw new EssentialServerException(6);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void release (int ExceptionType) throws EssentialServerException{
    //The int value ExceptionType indicate the EssentialServerException's type that the FileLocker class should throw if the file unlocking fails
    try{
        lock.release();
        fileChannel.close();
        randomAccessFile.close();
    }catch (IOException ee){
        throw new EssentialServerException(ExceptionType);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You could set a flag when `release()` is called, and implement `finalize()` to check for it and throw an exception otherwise. But I think it'd be better to just call `release()` from `finalize()` and be done with it.

Comment: Try writing all the public methods of your class so that they call the release method at the end.

Comment: Finalize is not guaranteed to be run.

Comment: There is no such thing, but you could implement [AutoCloseable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html), to at least allow developers to use the try-with-resources statement, which would guarantee that the FileLocker is closed.

Comment: I think try with resource is a possible scenario,that implements 'autoCloseabe' and I have elaborated in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly answer your question - I do not know a way to directly enforce this. However, I would like to refer you to the [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) interface. It allows you to write code that can be used in a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) code block.

Not knowing (ignoring really) all the details of your code, using it might look like something like this:

```
try (FileLocker locker = new FileLocker(filename)) {
  // Use locker
}
```

Optionally you can add your catch and finally blocks. But the point is that this guarantees that locker will be 'closed' before exiting the try-block.

Additionally, if `FileLocker` is only an arbitrary object that won't be further used inside the `try {}` block, other than releasing it again, then you could simplify this as follows:

```
try (new FileLocker(filename)) {
  // Your code during FileLocker
}
```

In order for this to work, your `FileLocker` will have to extend [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html). Actually, if your `FileLocker` will throw an `IOException`, you can also consider extending [`Closeable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) instead. You will be required to implement the `close` method, which would basically have to call your `release` method.

Comment: After a lot of attempts I find out that to gain what i want (make shure that the release() method is always called on an FileLocker object) is to extend the interface AutoCloseable and rename my release() method to close(). Using this way java shows a warning if the close() method isn't called on an FileLokcker object.

Answer (score 0):

> Locking a file is quite simple in Java. The FileChannel (Java Doc) provides all methods we need to lock files. The tryLock() (Java Doc) method will try to obtain the lock on the file without waiting. If the lock is acquired an instance of FileLock (Java Doc) is returned, otherwise this method returns null.
>
> FileLock is only for interprocess locking, javadoc reads:

"File locks are held on behalf of the entire Java virtual machine. They are not suitable for controlling access to a file by multiple threads within the same virtual machine."
To lock between java threads (same JVM) you need to use some shared lock. I would suggest within the file writing class to use a synchronized block (which according to these articles is likely to perform best):

**An alternative approach is to use a ReentrantLock :**

```
final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

public void write(...){
  try {
    lock.lock()
    // do the writing
  } finally {
    // forget this and you're screwed
    lock.unlock();
  }
}
```

This case uses the lock to resolve interleaving of writes, not concurrent access.Further concurrent lock is more feature rich.However sync lock does the task as well.[read doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html)

Both locks and reentrant locks however are mandtory to close.so **new try with resource feature is handy** that implements AutoCloseable interface, which is required for use with the new try-with-resource syntax. so you can write a simple wrapper like:

```
    public class LockWrapper implements AutoCloseable
{
    private final Lock _lock;
    public LockWrapper(Lock l) {
       this._lock = l;
    }

    public void lock() {
        this._lock.lock();
    }

    public void close() {
        this._lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Now you can write code like this:

```
try (LockWrapper someLock = new LockWrapper(new ReentrantLock()))
{
    someLock.lock();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @khakisshoiab for your answer. I understand what you mean. The problem is that I have an enormous quantity of code, and it contains a lot of points where is needed a lock on the same object (a file). I tried what you say - use lock Objects - but it caused the presence of a lockObject that literally flew across my code, beeing passed by a lot of methods. I've tried the solution I've showed you to be more comfortable (of course working on the same JVM) but I understand that might exist better solutions. I'm still searching them!

Comment: then try reenterant locks read about them,that ways you dont have to manage multiple locks for huge resources.

Comment: Again @khakishoiab I see your point of view. I'm studyng about reeterant locks. I want to be sure - before use them - that if I start two or three different processes using the same threads typology the reeterant lock (contaned in threads) still works for all processes at the same time (and not that I have two/three reeterant locks, each one for one process and all the threads it throws)